# Jquery not working properly on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using Jquery to animate containers from bottom to top as page loads. I am doing this by overwriting the top margin applied to the containers in the css file and assigning 0px with Jquery instead when the page loads. 
This is working nicely and smooth in Chrome and Firefox.
However explorer at times keeps the original css top-margin for the first container. 
I really want to make it work on Explorer so I can keep this feature in the page.

Here is the link to what I have:

http://as.sjsu.edu/asgov/index.jsp?val=bodBlogs

Here is the Jquery:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(function(){
    $('.director_box').animate({'margin-top': '0px'}, 500);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Nothing really works properly in IE, but jQuery usually is'nt the problem.

Comment: Why not update to jQuery 1.9.1? 1.8.3 has tons of known bugs.  //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Ok I wil do the update.

Comment: Why not update to jQuery 2.0, which does'nt support IE8 at all, problem solved !

Comment: @adeno. Good Idea! still the css would stay and containers would have huge margins in between. I guess i can specify different css for ie.